# How can I set the rules in Firebase database for particular user set without using firebase auth?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Understand this as I want to create a group chat feature into our current application. Like there are multiple teams and I want to allow teams to chat within themselves. Now I haven't used firebase auth for authentication. Users are signed in with other authentication system so I have an  arrayList of authenticated users. I want to set the security rules for firebase database that only user available in that arrayList can read or write the messages from database. How can I do that?

Comment: It is unclear how you identify the user. Are they signed in with another authentication system? Or are they self-identified only? Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to answer these questions, and provide more context on the problem.